# Trying to raise exception in Airflow DAG and getting "Broken DAG"

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I want my DAG to fail (while running) if cursor.rowcount > 0 is true.
This is the code:

```
def execute(self):
        self.hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=self.dest_redshift_conn_id)
        conn = self.hook.get_conn()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        log.info("Connected with " + self.dest_redshift_conn_id)
        log.info('Starting Query')
        print('Starting Query \n')
        cursor.execute("begin transaction;")
        sql_comm = self.read_queries_file()
        for command in sql_comm:
            sql_statement = command
            if sql_statement:
                log.info(sql_statement)
                log.info('\n')
                cursor.execute(sql_statement)
                res = cursor.fetchmany(10)
                if cursor.rowcount > 0:
                    raise Exception(res)
                else:
                    log.info('\nNo result found in the query')
        cursor.execute(" end transaction;")
        cursor.close()
        log.info("Select process is completed".format(self.dest_table))
```

I have pushed it to the Airflow and got "Broken DAG" error after restarting the Airflow services without running the DAG. [Error print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffxjX.png)

How can I fail the DAG inside my code and that the Airflow won't break?
Tried already to change the Exception type but didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed the `def execute(self, context)` to `def execute(self, **context)` and it's working now

Answer (score 0):

The execute method should receive the context argument. Try rewriting your code with the method firm as

```
def execute(self, context):
  ...
```

Comment: Hi, I have added in the execute the "context" and now im getting error from the DAG that calls the operator "execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'.
How this "execute" function is called? who is calling it and how? where should I add the "context" in the DAG after adding it in the operator?

Comment: Ok, first we need to know if the error is inside the custom operator or somewhere else. Try changing the operator for a BashOperator or PythonOperator and see if the Broken DAG error disappears. If it does, then we are sure that the error is in your custom operator. You might need to check the entire Operator definition. If you could public the entire class declaration it would be helpful

Comment: To answer your question, the execute method is run when the DAG is given to a worker and the worker starts to run the TaskInstance. This is controlled entirely by Airflow for you